# Query custom date field by month and day

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've added a a custom field named `date of birth` to all users. I would like to query the coming birthdays of all users in the next 7 days or so. How can I query by the month and day only and not the year?

```
<?php

        $args = array(
            'role'      => 'Subscriber',
            'meta_key'  => 'user_geboortedatum', // date of birth (ACF datefield)
            'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'     => 'ASC'
        );

       // The Query                         
       $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

       // User Loop
       if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) :

            foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {


            $user_string = 'user_' . $user->ID; ?>

                <h1><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></h1>
                <?php echo get_field('user_geboortedatum', $user_string); ?>



        <?php } // end for each ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Added the code. I don't know what argument to use to query the next 5 or so birthdays with a field containing the birth date (user_geboortedatum). ACF stores the birthdate like this YYYYMMDD.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far. You can expect people to right code for you. That is how you learn brother.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have created the field with ACF's Date Picker. Then its easy to display custom field value to front end. Use below codes where you want to display your Date of Birth field Value in Day and Month Format :

```
<?php 

      $date = get_field('date-of-birth', false, false);
      $date = new DateTime($date); ?>

      Date Of Birth : <?php echo $date->format('j M');
 ?>
```

Comment: Hey Sajjadur, I probbably didn't explain clear it enough. The goals is to query the comming 5 users birthdays of all users. I added a Date picker field to the users named birthdate. And now I want to query the first 5 birthdays comming up.

Comment: Still i don't understand your goal? Sorry please elaborate it more in a programming way